# How to kill selenium running as a subprocess?

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

Given the code below, which runs selenium as a `multiprocessing.Process`. Despite the process being terminated on macOS Ventura `13.0.1`, selenium window stays open. Why does the window stay? how to force its termination?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


def func():
    driver = Chrome()
    driver.get('https://google.com')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=func)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    p.join(timeout=1)
    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()
```

A current workaround I'm using:

```
os.system("ps aux | grep Google | awk ' { print $2 } ' | xargs kill -9")
```

Comment: What is "Selenium window"? Is it a browser window?

Comment: yes ....................

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines:

```
def func():
    driver = Chrome()
    driver.get('https://google.com')
    driver.quit()
```

This should close each window, after the function concludes.

See [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to modify function `func`, then pass to it the Chrome driver as an argument instead of it creating the driver itself.

1. The main process starts a child process, `run_selenium` that starts `func` in a daemon thread. It then waits for up to 1 second for `func` to complete.
2. If the selenium thread (`func`) is still alive, a call to `stop` is made on the underlying driver service. `run_selenium` then terminates and a long with its daemon `func` thread.

```py
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


def func(driver):
    import time

    # Modified to run forever:
    while True:
        driver.get('https://google.com')
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.get('https://bing.com')
        time.sleep(5)

def run_selenium():
    driver = Chrome()
    # Selenium will terminate when we do:
    t = Thread(target=func, args=(driver,), daemon=True)
    t.start()
    t.join(1)

    # Did selenium actually finish?
    if t.is_alive():
        driver.service.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=run_selenium)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print('Selenium terminated; I can now go on to do other things...')
    ...
```